# Pyspark: Get substring of Column Name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rename

I'm new to PySpark and want to change my column names as most of them have an annoying prefix.
My column names are like this:

```
e1013_var1
e1014_var2
e1015_var3
Data_date_stamp
```

If existent, I want to remove the `EXXX_` from the column names, how to do that? As I also want everything in Uppercase, my code so far looks like this

```
for col in df.columns:
    df= df.withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())
```

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that avoids a *for* cycle is using [`toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF.html) to rename all the columns of a Spark dataframe

```
import re

df_new = df.toDF(*[re.sub('e\d+_', '', c).upper() for c in df.columns])

print(df_new.columns)
# ['VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR3', 'DATA_DATE_STAMP']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the annoying prefix's format is `e[digits]_`, we can use `re.sub`:

```py
import re

for col in df.columns:
    new_col = re.sub(r"e\d+_", "", col).upper()
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, new_col)
```